# Sending clickable (hyperlinked) content to iFrame

Tags: html, iframe

In an HTML file, I have a list of hyperlinked images within  and use the target attribute to send each image to an iFrame within another  below the first. No problems at all, the images show up as expected, but sometimes the image is too large for the target and magnifying it with the mouse can lead to very little of the image showing, requiring scroll bar navigation. I would like to be able to send information (such as the hypertext link for each image) to the iFrame target so that the user can click on the displayed image, not to enlarge it, rather to open it up in a separate window so they can see the entire image. Is this possible?